# How to assign Rank in SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column (impact/hr) which gets populated after some calculations. Now I would like to assign each row a rank. For example Maximum dollar amt gets the rank of 1. Any tips to write an expression would be appreciated. Thank you. [image]

Comment: Is Impact/Hr based on a calculated field in the Dataset or embedded in the textbox? If the latter, can you create it as a calculated field in the Dataset? Also, is this something that could be calculated when generating the Dataset instead of doing it in the report itself?

Comment: Hi Ian, calculated field is embedded in the textbox. Like you said it can be achieved by changing the SQL that I used to create the dataset. If no other option left I will have to use it. Thanks though

Comment: Maybe easiest if you can do it in T-SQL... This answer has a few options, but I don't think any are as simple as a plain old T-SQL ranking function, even if they might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826440/ssrs-row-group-column-group-rownumber-issue

Answer (score 1):

Just add some custom code in `Report`-`Report Properties...`-`Code`:

```
Dim Rank AS Integer

Function GetRank() AS Integer
  Rank = Rank + 1
  Return Rank
End Function
```

In your tablix's detail cell where you want the rank, use the following formula:

```
=Code.GetRank()
```

Each time it processes that cell, it adds one to the rank and displays the result.

Answer (score 1):

It may be your secondary option !

You can arrange the `Impact\Hr` in ascending order and the show the Rank by using `RowNumber` function.

For More info see the [RowNumber](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rank function.

select [Impact per Hr], [My Rank] = Rank() over (order by [Impact per Hr] desc)

then use asc/desc depending on which value you want to be ranked high or low.
This is independent of any order by statement as well

Rank() is preferable to Row_Number() for applications like this because rows of the same value will have the same Rank, but will have a different Row_Number.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add the following code in code section of reports properties in Reports Builder.

```
Public dim previousValue as Integer = 0
Public dim i as Integer = 0
Public dim flag as Boolean = False
Public dim lastRank as Integer = 1

Public Function Rank(sourceValue as Integer ) As Integer

if previousValue = sourceValue
   i = i + 1
   flag = True
end if 
     
if previousValue > sourceValue
    lastRank = lastRank + 1
    flag = False
end if

previousValue =sourceValue

if flag = True 
    return lastRank
else
    lastRank = lastRank + i
    i = 0
    return lastRank
end if
 
End Function
```

Step 2: Call the above function from the cell where you want to display rank like this:

```
=code.Rank(SUM(Fields!SumTotal_Ending_Balance.Value))
```